# PHP - Handling additional arguments

Tags: php, oop, arguments, overloading

Consider the following case:

```
class Factory {
    private $x = 1;
    private $y = 2;
    private $z = 3;

    public function create(string $instance) {
        return new $instance($this->x, $this->y, $this->z);
    }
}

class A {
    private $x;

    public function __construct ($x) {
        $this->x = $x;
    }

    public function display() {
        echo "<pre>$this->x</pre>";
    }
}

class B {
    private $x;
    private $y;
    private $z;

    public function __construct ($x, $y, $z) {
        $this->x = $x;
        $this->y = $y;
        $this->z = $z;
    }

    public function display() {
        echo "<pre>$this->x</pre>";
        echo "<pre>$this->y</pre>";
        echo "<pre>$this->z</pre>";
    }
}

$factory = new Factory;

$a = $factory->create("A");
$a->display();

$b = $factory->create("B");
$b->display();
```

As you can see, the factory will always provide 3 `arguments` when it creates a new instance. But in the `class A`, only 1 `argument` is needed by the constructor. Since php does not have the usual method overloading, so this does not cause an issue. But just to be safe, should I add an argument list parameter to the `contructor` of `class A` something like :

```
public function __construct ($x, ... $ignore) { ... }
```

to catch those unnecessary arguments as I know it will get those additional arguments every time. Or is the existing code sufficient?

Comment: try to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php for your class A, if you need the args - if not leave it as it is. Also in your factory you should use the name of the class, not a variable, what will happen if you put `a` instead of `A`? Imho is better to check for that before you build your class.

Comment: And what will you do with `$ignore`?

Comment: You can validate the number of arguments using func_num_args to handle it http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php

Comment: But in the end I think your design needs more work to it, you can improve it a lot. As an example you can impl a DI container or a base class for this 2 classes...

Comment: @u_mulder nothing, that's the point.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass in more variables, than required in a functions definition, those extra variables will be ignored (sample: https://3v4l.org/fNfAQ).

But this might be an indication, that you are trying to do too much with this particular factory and you might have better results by using a DI container.

Or you might need to have separate factories, for creating instances with different dependencies, instead of making a singe "make everything" factory.

Comment: Indeed different factories is better, but it won't be useful if I have a bunch of similar B - Z classes with A being the only exception. But as they are simply ignored, I will stick with the existing code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing separate parameters, you could use an associative array for all the constructors.

```
class A {
    private $x;

    public function __construct ($params) {
        $this->x = $params['x'];
    }

    public function display() {
        echo "<pre>$this->x</pre>";
    }
}

class B {
    private $x;
    private $y;
    private $z;

    public function __construct ($params) {
        $this->x = $params['x'];
        $this->y = $params['y'];
        $this->z = $params['z'];
    }

    public function display() {
        echo "<pre>$this->x</pre>";
        echo "<pre>$this->y</pre>";
        echo "<pre>$this->z</pre>";
    }
}
```

Then the factory can do:

```
public function create($instance) {
    return new $instance(array('x' => $this->x, 'y' => $this->y, 'z' => $this->z));
}
```

Comment: This would violate [POLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment), since you would have no way of knowing, what parameters a class instance requires in the constructor, without actually reading that constructor's code.

Comment: @tereško Is it really any worse than expecting all the constructors to take their parameters in the same fixed order, except that some are optional?

Comment: I guess he could use an ordinary array: `new $instance(array($this->x, $this->y, $this->z))` and the constructors can use whichever array elements they want.

Comment: @tereško POLA, that's something new for me... quite astonishing...pun intended.

Comment: @Barmar Indeed an associative array is an interesting solution, I can think of  implementing it for a case involving a coordinate-system. `A` class may be 1-D. so only `x` axis value  will suffice whereas `B` will be a 3-D requiring all 3 axes.